# EntryPointNotFoundException when running EConnect sample console app

Tags: c#, exception, econnect, entrypointnotfoundexcept

I'm trying to run an EConnect sample console app but it keeps coming up with System.EntryPointNotFoundException in mscorlib.dll. I can't for the life of me figure out why its doing this, especially because I have successfully ran this app in the past and now all of a sudden it doesn't work.

Any ideas what could be causing this problem or at least some ideas how I could get more information about the problem. Im not sure how to catch the exception and display more info because the exception seems comes up without going into the catch block.

Here is the code for the app Im trying to run, I've tried tracing through it and it seems like the exception is occuring around this line:
e.CreateEntity(sConnectionString, sCustomerDocument);

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect;
using Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect.Serialization;

namespace eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication
{
    class Test
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            string sCustomerDocument;
            string sXsdSchema;
            string sConnectionString;

            using (eConnectMethods e = new eConnectMethods())
            {
                try
                {
                    // Create the customer data file
                    SerializeCustomerObject("Customer.xml");

                    // Use an XML document to create a string representation of the customer
                    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xmldoc.Load("Customer.xml");
                    sCustomerDocument = xmldoc.OuterXml;

                    // Specify the Microsoft Dynamics GP server and database in the connection string
                    sConnectionString = @"data source=localhost;initial catalog=TWO;integrated security=SSPI;persist security info=False;packet size=4096";

                    // Create an XML Document object for the schema
                    XmlDocument XsdDoc = new XmlDocument();

                    // Create a string representing the eConnect schema
                    sXsdSchema = XsdDoc.OuterXml;

                    // Pass in xsdSchema to validate against.
                    e.CreateEntity(sConnectionString, sCustomerDocument);
                }
                // The eConnectException class will catch eConnect business logic errors.
                // display the error message on the console
                catch (eConnectException exc)
                {
                    Console.Write(exc.ToString());
                }
                // Catch any system error that might occurr.
                // display the error message on the console
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Write(ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Call the Dispose method to release the resources
                    // of the eConnectMethds object
                    e.Dispose();
                }
            } // end of using statement
        }

        public static void SerializeCustomerObject( string filename )
        {
            try
            {
                // Instantiate an eConnectType schema object
                eConnectType eConnect = new eConnectType();

                // Instantiate a RMCustomerMasterType schema object
                RMCustomerMasterType customertype = new RMCustomerMasterType();

                // Instantiate a taUpdateCreateCustomerRcd XML node object
                taUpdateCreateCustomerRcd customer = new taUpdateCreateCustomerRcd();

                // Create an XML serializer object
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(eConnect.GetType());

                // Populate elements of the taUpdateCreateCustomerRcd XML node object
                customer.CUSTNMBR = "Customer001";
                customer.CUSTNAME = "Customer 1";
                customer.ADDRESS1 = "2002 60th St SW";
                customer.ADRSCODE = "Primary";
                customer.CITY = "NewCity";
                customer.ZIPCODE = "52302";

                // Populate the RMCustomerMasterType schema with the taUpdateCreateCustomerRcd XML node
                customertype.taUpdateCreateCustomerRcd = customer;
                RMCustomerMasterType [] mySMCustomerMaster = {customertype};

                // Populate the eConnectType object with the RMCustomerMasterType schema object
                eConnect.RMCustomerMasterType = mySMCustomerMaster;

                // Create objects to create file and write the customer XML to the file
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
                XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(fs, new UTF8Encoding());

                // Serialize the eConnectType object to a file using the XmlTextWriter.
                serializer.Serialize(writer, eConnect);
                writer.Close();
            }
            // catch any errors that occur and display them to the console
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output from the debug:

```
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. 
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics\eConnect 12.0\eConnect Samples\CSHARP Console Application\bin\Debug\eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect\12.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect.Serialization\12.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect.Serialization.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x2af0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2af4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2ae4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics\eConnect 12.0\eConnect Samples\CSHARP Console Application\bin\Debug\eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'Microsoft.GeneratedCode'. 
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Exception thrown: 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
The thread 0x2a40 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2a58 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[10848] eConnect_CSharp_ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I have also reinstalled eConnect numerous times, and like I said before this was all working perfectly fine until today so I dont know whats going on. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Well, I found my issue, turns out I had the Just My Code debugging option turned off, turned that back on and it works again

Answer (score 1):

All fixed, I had the Just My Code debugging option turned off, turning it back on fixed the issue. For anyone else with the same problem all I did was go to Tools>Options>Debugging>General>check Enable Just My Code